# Double Over Precision

Tags: objective-c

Apologies if this has been asked already - not sure what to search for.

Simple bit of code:

```
double x = 4505;
double y = 1000;
double z = 1000000;
double result = (x * y) / z;
```

Answer should be 4.505; but I get:

```
result = 4.5049999999999999
```

The values of x, y and z could be anything, and sometimes I need that level of precision in the result but I can't see why this is happening.

**The Question is** how to I remove the rounding error so that I can re-run further calculations on the decimal value without getting erroneous results and at the same time maintain high level of precision for numbers that need it.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a [Floating Point Rounding Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error).  Also there is [this](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/rounding/).

If you want `result` rounded to 3 decimal places, then use:

```
result = floor(result * 1000.0) / 1000.0;
```

or just during presentation:

```
NSLog(@"result = %.3f", result);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the problem is I have no idea how many decimal places I'll need, totally depends on the numbers fed in, sometimes I'll need 16 decimal places, other times 1 or none.  Main issue is I'm taking the decimal value and re-processing it - and getting an irronious result